# Why substr() does not return correct value?

Tags: php

I have a following code:

```
$string = "aaa<test>xxx</test>bbb";
echo substr($string, 9);
```

As a result should be:
    **xxx</test>bbb**

In the meantime I receive just:
**xxxbbb**

What happened with the tag? Why this function automatically crops it! 
If I replace < with [ works... I would like to obtain just a closing tag in my variable.

Comment: i think you're looking in browser output... check the source.

Comment: In other words, "View source" from your browser... and I'll bet you actually see "xxx</test>bb" :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [output html tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8630675/output-html-tags)

Answer (score 2):

If you look into source, you will have also `</test>` tag. It's not visible in the browser because it has been already rendered as nothing.

For printing this kind of results, use

```
var_dump( substr($string, 9) );
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine if you do it in the command line. Are you looking at your output through a browser? The browser might be trying to parse the tag and then ignoring it.

Comment: Oh yeah! So silly. Suggested by firebug which cropped the tag, but in real source code it shows the tag. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Its because browser take `<test></test>` as html tag so you can not see it in browser.

View source will surly help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the view source of the php file in a browser(crtl+u in chrome), you can see

```
xxx</test>bbb
```

You can see it otherwise since `</test>` is interpreted as a tag by the browser.